# Control shape overlap in Python's turtle?

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I am writing a program that takes user input for (1) number of sides of the shape to be drawn, (2) how large to draw it, (3) how many to draw, and (4) how many colors to use. The turtle then spaces that many of that shape around in a circle, all sharing a vertex at the center of the circle.

What's bothering me is that if the shapes overlap at the very end, the last shapes will be on top of everything, whereas I would like them tucked in behind the shapes in front of them like the rest.

I've managed to determine that the number of shapes that overlap incorrectly depends on the number of sides of the shape - for a triangle for example, there is no overlap with 1-6 shapes. With 7-12, one shape overlaps incorrectly. With 13-18, two shapes overlap incorrectly. And so on.

So far, I've written for it to consider the first and last groups of shapes as their own things, poly1 and poly2, and to start I'd at least like to be able to tell it to draw poly2 behind poly1.

Main thing: is this even possible with turtle? And then, if so, how can I do it? (using 3.5)

Edit: I'm thinking this is probably impossible. Everything I'm hearing is that turtle can only draw on top of existing shapes. But it was also suggested I include a screenshot in case it adds clarity; here's an image of what turtle draws (when told to draw 9 triangles with 3 different colors).

[image]

My goal is to make that full triangle tucked under the one at 12 o clock, but still over the one before it, like it was originally drawn.

Comment: That's because `turtle` puts each shape on top of the last. You would somehow have to redraw part of the first shape to overlap the last shape. (Also: Your post might not be completely clear to everyone, it might help if you posted some screenshots)

Answer (score 2):

> I'm thinking this is probably impossible.

You underestimate the gumption of turtles.  Here's my initial example that exhibits the asymmetric problem you wish to fix:

```
import math
from itertools import cycle
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

COLORS = cycle(['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow'])

def rotate_polygon(polygon, angle):

    theta = math.radians(angle)
    sin, cos = math.sin(theta), math.cos(theta)

    return [(x * cos - y * sin, x * sin + y * cos) for x, y in polygon]

def fill_polygon(turtle, polygon, color):

    turtle.color(color)

    for vertex in polygon:
        turtle.goto(vertex)

        if not turtle.filling():
            turtle.begin_fill()

    turtle.end_fill()

# triangle cursor 5x in size and X translated 50 pixels
polygon = ((100, -28.85), (50, 57.75), (0, -28.85))

screen = Screen()

yertle = Turtle(visible=False)
yertle.penup()

for angle in range(0, 360, 30):
    rotated_polygon = rotate_polygon(polygon, angle)
    color = next(COLORS)
    fill_polygon(yertle, rotated_polygon, color)

screen.exitonclick()
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

We really want the final yellow triangle to be tucked neatly under the initial red one, like an ever rising Escher staircase.  I chose this illustration as it has multiple overlaps, the final yellow triangle should in theory not only underlap the red, but both the green and blue that follow the red.  Similarly, the blue and green that preceed the final yellow should underlap the red. Etc.

[image]

My code above is more complex than is needed to draw this particular illustration but needs extra structure to support the following enhancement:

One approach would be to work out the intersection and not draw that portion of the newest triangle.  Another approach is to draw the new triangle, but recolor in the the triange intersection that should be underlapped.  This later approach is what I implement below, using an existing Python function to get the intersection via the Sutherland-Hodgman polygon clipping algorithm:

```
import math
from itertools import cycle
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

COLORS = cycle(['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow'])

def clip(subjectPolygon, clipPolygon):

    # obtain this code from:
    # https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sutherland-Hodgman_polygon_clipping#Python

    return outputList

def rotate_polygon(polygon, angle):

    theta = math.radians(angle)
    sin, cos = math.sin(theta), math.cos(theta)

    return [(x * cos - y * sin, x * sin + y * cos) for x, y in polygon]

def fill_polygon(turtle, polygon, color):

    turtle.color(color)

    for vertex in polygon:
        turtle.goto(vertex)

        if not turtle.filling():
            turtle.begin_fill()

    turtle.end_fill()

# triangle cursor 5x in size and X translated 50 pixels
polygon = ((100, -28.85), (50, 57.75), (0, -28.85))

screen = Screen()

yertle = Turtle(visible=False)
yertle.speed('slowest')  # slowly so we can see redrawing
yertle.penup()

polygons = []
POLYGON, COLOR = 0, 1

for angle in range(0, 360, 30):
    rotated_polygon = rotate_polygon(polygon, angle)
    color = next(COLORS)
    fill_polygon(yertle, rotated_polygon, color)
    polygons.append((rotated_polygon, color))

    # The -3 here is empirical and really should be calculated, an exercise for the reader
    for forward, backward in enumerate(range(-3, 1 - len(polygons), -1)):
        if polygons[forward] != polygons[backward]:
            try:
                intersection_polygon = clip(rotated_polygon, polygons[forward][POLYGON])
            except (IndexError, ZeroDivisionError):
                break  # because clip() can throw an error when no intersection

            if intersection_polygon:
                fill_polygon(yertle, intersection_polygon, polygons[forward][COLOR])
            else:
                break  # if no intersection, don't look any further
        else:
            break  # avoid testing against polygons clockwise from this one (needs work)

screen.exitonclick()
```

OUTPUT

[image]